# How to change which part of the image will be displayed when I hover over it?

Tags: jquery, css

I use colorbox for the popup on the website: http://vmelab.com . Section: OUR PORTFOLIO.
I've switched default image for previous, next, close buttons and set up a different one. But it shows wrong parts of the image while I hover cursor over it. 
How do I change it, I don't see such attributes in CSS.

Thanks eveyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the `background-position` of the `:hover` style for the next, prev, and close buttons:

For example:

```
#cboxNext:hover {
    background-position: -46px -46px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!